# Barcode4j - Generate check digit in an EAN13 barcode

Tags: barcode4j

When yo generate a barcode with Barcode4j as an image, you could obtain the human readable text, too, for instance:

[EAN13 barcode example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCkKM.png)

In this picture we can see that the human readable text is: **1000000012026**

In this example the barcode has been generated with the code **100000001202** and the number **6** is the check digit added by Barcode4j generator.

So, my question is: Is possible obtain the check digit of an EAN13 generated barcode with Barcode4j? Because I know how to render this as a image, but I don't know how to obtain the human readable text, as a plain text.

Regards,

Miguel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Barcode4j plugin, you can calculate the checksum with the barcode format you need. In Java 7, you can calculate the checkSum as this way:

```
private String calculateCodeWithcheckSum(String codigo){
   EAN13Bean generator = new EAN13Bean();
   UPCEANLogicImpl impl = generator.createLogicImpl();
   codigo += impl.calcChecksum(codigo);
   return codigo;
}
```

First, you need the `EAN13` barcode format, so you can get the class that the plugin provides you, and call its only method: `createLogicImpl()`.

This method is used to give you a class of type `UPCEANLogicImpl`. 
This is the class you need, because you can find in it the method to calculate the checkSum. So, you only have to call the method calcChecksum giving your code (**100000001202**), and will give you the checkSum value (**6**).

You can check it in the next web: http://www.gs1.org/check-digit-calculator

Adding your code and the checkSum value will give you the value you need (**1000000012026**)

Answer (score 1):

In case you what to compute the check digit without importing a java library here's the code:

```
public static String ean13CheckDigit(String barcode) {
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        int c = Character.getNumericValue(barcode.charAt(i));
        s += c * ( i%2 == 0? 1: 3);
    }
    s = (10 - s % 10) % 10;
    barcode += s;
    return barcode;
}
```